# What does the __module__ arg do in pydantic.create_model?

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm currently building a Pydantic model builder using `create_model`, and reading the help text I see:

```
__module__: The name of the module that the model belongs to,
    if `None` the value is taken from `sys._getframe(1)`
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means, but it seems to make Python think I have a module that doesn't exist, i.e.

```py
>>> import pydantic

>>> model = pydantic.create_model("Test", __module__="test", foo(str, ...))

>>> # Asking what the model is tells me it has a module `test`
>>> model
<class `test.Test`>

>>> # The model is not referenced by any module though
>>> test = model(foo="bar")
>>> test
Test(foo='bar')
```

I'm not really sure what to make of it, what I would use it for, or if/how I would distinguish between `model("Test", __module__="a", ...)` and `model("Test", __module__="b", ...)`.

Thanks in advance.